Relation between chiral symmetry in condensed matter and chiral symmetry in QFT？
In QFT the chiral transformation (also called axial transformation) is:
$$\psi \rightarrow e^{-\theta \gamma_5}\psi$$
It is a global continuous phase transformation, where $\theta$ is an arbitrary real number and $\gamma_5$ is the fifth Dirac matrix. As an example, the massless Dirac field $\mathcal{L}=i\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\psi$ possesses this symmetry. For a (single particle) Dirac Hamiltonian $H_D=-i\gamma^0\vec{\gamma}\cdot\nabla$, there is $[H_D,\gamma^5]=0$, furthermore, one can define the chiral projection operator $P_L=\frac{1-\gamma^5}{2}$ and $P_R=\frac{1+\gamma^5}{2}$, thus the Lagrangian and Hamiltonian can be rewritten as a left-hand and a right-hand part separately, e.g. $H_D=P_A H P_A +P_B H P_B$ (under the chiral-weyl representation).
In condensed matter physics, the chiral symmetry (also called sublattice symmetry) is:
$$H\rightarrow\Gamma H \Gamma^\dagger=-H$$
It is a $Z(2)$ discrete transform. As an example, the SSH model possesses this symmetry. Whereas for the single particle Hamiltonian $H_{SSH}$, there is $\{H_{SSH},\Gamma\}=0$, it's completely different compared with QFTs. However, similar to QFT's method, one can define the projection operator $P_A=\frac{1-\gamma^5}{2}$ and $P_B=\frac{1+\gamma^5}{2}$, the entire Hamiltonian can be projected into in to $H_{SSH}=P_A H P_B +P_B H P_A$, which means $H_{SSH}$ is off-diagonal.
My question is, if there's a connection between them that can let to some enlightening understanding?
This question also makes me wonder: in some places people put their attention on the Dirac operator $D\equiv \partial_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu} $ rather than the Hamiltonian of Dirac field $H_D$, indeed, for Dirac operator, $\{D,\gamma^5\}=0$. Then under chiral-weyl basis, the Euclidean part (i.e. $\mu=1,2,3$) of the $D$ can be rewritten into some off-diagonal form similar to CMP. Seemingly this terminology finally gets some consistency, but I don't know why people turn to focus on $D$.

I don't think they are the same thing at all (eg, the HEP version exists only in even spacetime dimensions). But it is an interesting question, I don't know why the CMP version is called a chiral symmetry in the first place.
